# Site not working in IIS but working in visual studio debugging mode Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a website under development, it is located at: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\

It works fine when I use visual studio's debugging mode, I can login and do whatever I intend to. However, When I access the site in IIS by typing the URL: `http://localhost/site/`, it seems the database connection is not working. The error message is: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When running in IIS, it doesn't trigger the break points I have set in VS. And it's working alright in visual studio, I can't debug and find what is wrong at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you have correct .Net Framework selected in Application Pool...

Comment: can you post the full stack trace of that error message? Did you create an application for "site" in IIS?

Comment: how is the web app connecting to the database? if your connection string is using integrated auth, your app pool identity must have access to the database.

Comment: 1. I have Asp.Net v4.0 as app pool. 2. I have other sites that are working in IIS. 3. The app connects to db using connection string stored in web.config.

Comment: I removed the site and re-created the application, now it works, everything was default. I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I was almost to going mad when I find a resource that was saying that it's not enough to have just the engine running but also the SQL Server Browser, I hope this can solve you're problem.